# Emails are sent to root user account instead of orig recpient

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Although emails are said to be delivered by `/var/log/maillog` I can't see emails in that user account; instead all emails are received by `root` user only. What I need to verify so that mails sent by `info@example.com` will be delivered to recipient `admin@example.com`, but not the `root` user account.

I have this line in `postfix/main.cf`, so I think that my machine knows it is `example.com`:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

Comment: Is `example.com` your machine, and does your machine know that?

Comment: i have this line in postfix/main.cf mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

Comment: Is `$mydomain` actually the `example.com` you use in your question?

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your maillog when delivering an email?